# On iOS SDK, Is there a way to programatically connect to a specific Bluetooth PAN?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, pan

As title stated, basically I am building a Raspberry Pi to use Bluetooth PAN to provide device to device communication, I don't want to use BLE as it is not designed for high volume traffic.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to initiate bluetooth pairing or connection to a paired device programmatically on iOS.
There are few exceptions however:
1. Pairing and connection to bluetooth external accessories (MFi) is possible using Bluetooth Accessory Picker and the External Accessory Framework
2. Core Bluetooth api can be used to communicate with BLE devices

For Bluetooth PAN profile, the only choice is to connect the devices manually.
You can for example activate connection sharing (hotspot) on iPhone and let the raspberry connect to the hotspot.

You can follow this link to set up hotspot connection sharing on iPhone:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023

Cheers,
Hichem

Comment: I know how to do it manually - so I just want to look for a way to do that programatically so user doesn't need to figure out which device to pair when there are more than one around